# windows ruby debug ide gem install fail

Tags: ruby, debugging, ide, rubygems, devkit

I can't find anything on this (with any solutions, that is) that has the same exact problem as me. I can't install a certain gem on my system. I run:

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
```

Everything is installed fine right now. Ruby 1.9.3 and the Ruby DevKit are installed as well. I've installed ruby-debug-base19x version 0.11.30.pre3 as well and that went smoothly. Right now, this is the only thing giving me problems. I've tried everything - restarting my machine, and even reinstalling Ruby and the Ruby DevKit.

Here's the error from the gem_make.out file:

```
    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... no
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for rb_method_entry() in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating ruby_debug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c: In function 'filename_cmp':
ruby_debug.c:522:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'filename_cmp_impl'
ruby_debug.c:530:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'realpath'
ruby_debug.c:530:34: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
linking shared-object ruby_debug.so
ruby_debug.o: In function `filename_cmp':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre6\ext\ruby_debug/ruby_debug.c:530: undefined reference to `realpath'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ruby_debug.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre6/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:530:in `block in build_extensions'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `build_extensions'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
mkrf_conf.rb:25:in `rescue in <main>'
mkrf_conf.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

My apologies for the length of errors - I'm just tired of restarting from the beginning with  no luck multiple times and making sure that everything I'm doing is correct and not overlooking anything. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [recent commit](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-base19/commit/c2c77f47343ee8e907efe5356c5df405e114b944) may have fixed this. Can you try pre9?

Comment: I actually re-executed the DevKit's variables in the batch file, resulting in it working (finally!) - so if anyone is having troubles such as this, that might help. :-)